# Grouping by two columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

df:
[image: this is the data frame i have please click the link to view]

Expected output:

[image: this is the output I required]

the code I used is:

```
grp_df2= clean_df.filter(['member_casual','Difference','Week_day'])    
grp_df2.groupby(['member_casual','Week_day']).Difference.apply(np.mean).reset_index()
```

the output:
[image: output I have]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Please [do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)